# Spring Solr - Using multiple clients to different services

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data-solr

I am working with an application that aggregates data from multiple sources. In this case I need to connect to two different Solr services with unrelated data.  To this end I set up two different data repositories. I have defined the beans as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages={"foo.utilities.solr.repos.gcr"}, multicoreSupport=true)
public class GcrSolrContext {

    @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient("http://foo:8086/solr/gcr");
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient client) throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(client);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I cannot figure out how to have two completely independent Solr clients, with each pointing at different urls. As the beans solrClient() and solrTemplate() are needed, and trying to create a new Context with different URLs simply gets the solrClient and solrTemplate bean overwritten with the beans created first. Each client works fine if they are the only Solr clients defined.

**In short, how can I create two (or more) different Spring Solr clients, each connecting to different URLS?**

**Additional Information is response to comments...**

I have attempted to simply recreate the SolrContext class with different configurations.Consider the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages={"foo.utilities.solr.repos.different"}, multicoreSupport=true)
public class DifferentSolrContext {

    @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient("http://SomethingDifferent:8086/solr/something");
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient client) throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(client);
    }
}
```

What happens here is that the @Bean's solrClient, and solrTemplate get overridden when the beans are created during startup.

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'solrClient' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=yyySolrContext; factoryMethodName=solrClient; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in foo.utilities.solr.GcrSolrContext] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=xxxSolrContext; factoryMethodName=solrClient; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in foo.utilities.solr.XxxSolrContext]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'solrTemplate' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=yyySolrContext; factoryMethodName=solrTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in foo.utilities.solr.GcrSolrContext] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=haystackSolrContext; factoryMethodName=solrTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in foo.utilities.solr.XxxSolrContext]
```

Testing shows that the URL is indeed only the first bean instantiated. I have also tried renaming the second context beans to something else, but then the Solr functionality can't locate/identify the beans.

Here is the error thrown when trying to define more than one SolrClient.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: solrClient2,solrClient
```

In short it appears that only one URL is possible for the Spring Solr Data  library.  (note: using version 2.1.4) Does anyone have more than one URL (not just core) working under Spring Solr data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there are multiple beans of the same type within the same Spring context, disambiguation is required when using autowiring.  The following should work:

> Configuration for first Solr server

```
@Configuration
public class PrimarySolrContext {
  @Bean
  public SolrClient primarySolrClient() {
    return new HttpSolrClient(...);
  }

  @Bean("primary")
  public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() {
    return new SolrTemplate(primarySolrClient());
  }
}
```

> Configuration for second Solr server

```
@Configuration
public class SecondarySolrContext {
  @Bean
  public SolrClient secondarySolrClient() {
    return new HttpSolrClient(...);
  }

  @Bean("secondary")
  public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() {
    return new SolrTemplate(secondarySolrClient());
  }
}
```

> Using the `SolrTemplate`s

```
@Service
public class SearchService {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("primary")
  private SolrTemplate primarySolrTemplate;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("secondary")
  private SolrTemplate secondarySolrTemplate;
}
```

This works because:

1. The first `SolrTemplate` refers to its `SolrClient` directly through an unambiguous method call (`primarySolrClient()`).
2. The second `SolrTemplate` refers to its `SolrClient` directly through an unambiguous method call (`secondarySolrClient()`).
3. The first `SolrTemplate` is unambiguously named (`@Bean("primary")`).
4. The second `SolrTemplate` is also unambiguously named (`@Bean("secondary")`).
5. The `SolrTemplate`s are injected unambiguously using their unique names through `@Qualifier`.

More `SolrTemplate`s can be initialized and injected in this fashion.

A sample project is available [on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/44423675) demonstrating this.

Comment: It doesn't work, the error is - A component required a bean named 'solrClient' that could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

create another bean for spring to use solr, this is easy and clean :

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages={"foo.utilities.solr.repos.xxx"}, multicoreSupport=true)
public class XXXSolrContext {

    @Bean
    public SolrClient getClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient("http://foo:8086/solr/xxx");
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate getTemplate(SolrClient client) throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(client);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done this. It does not work, as the beans get overridden by the first instance.  What I need is to point to a different SERVER, not core.  Here is from the startup logs "Overriding bean definition for bean 'solrClient' with a different definition: replacing ..."  There is a similar message for the solrTemplate bean.

Comment: it's overridden by Spring?

Comment: yes. See additional comments added to the question.